# How to prove that the distillable entanglement satisfies $E_D(|\psi_d\rangle\!\langle\psi_d|)\ge \log d$?

Tags: entanglement, state-distillation

If I have a pure state vector:
$$
\left|\psi_d\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum^{d}_{i=1}\left|ii\right\rangle
$$
then the distillable entanglement satisfies:
$$
E_{D}(\left|\psi_d\right\rangle\langle\psi_d|)\geq\log d.
$$
I am not seeing how to prove this as I thought if I have a pure state then the distillable Entanglement is equal to the entanglement entropy which is $\leq\log d$.

Comment: please add a link to where you encountered this statement (by editing the post, not in the comments)

Comment: I have a lecture notes but it's not public according to my professor. I can screenshot the theorem if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distillable entanglement of this state is *equal* $\log d$ ***by definition***. Thus, both $E_D(\lvert \psi_d\rangle\langle\psi_d\rvert)\ge \log d$ and $E_D(\lvert \psi_d\rangle\langle\psi_d\rvert)\le \log d$ holds true.

More generally, the distillable entanglement of a pure state is equal to the Shannon entropy $-\sum p_k\log p_k$ of its Schmidt coefficients $p_k$ (equivalently, the von Neumann entropy of either reduced density matrix) by definition. In the case of the state you give, this entropy equals $\log d$.